# Приоритеты операций в языке программирования Java

Tags: java, переменные, операторы

Речь о приоритете операторов в Java.

Итак, уже не раз наталкиваюсь на такие вот интересные таблички, в которых операторы выставлены в приоритете их выполнения в программе. Типичный пример: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/ 
Можно поискать и другие варианты, но все они более-менее схожи. Во всех таблицах, которые попадались мне на глаза, постфиксные унарные операторы инкремента и декремента имеют явный приоритет над своими префиксными аналогами. Следовательно, стоило бы ожидать, что в составном выражении, которое содержит, как постфиксный инкремент/декремент, так и префиксный, изначально должен вычисляться именно тот инкремент/декремент, который был записан в постфиксной форме. Хорошо, давайте тогда рассмотрим небольшой пример. Возьмём следующий кусок кода:

```
 int y = 10;
 int z = ++y * y--;
 System.out.println(z);
```

Что мы здесь имеем? Я вижу целых 4 операции в данном составном выражении. Ключевой операций здесь является операция присваивания, но она будет выполнена в самую последнюю очередь, так как имеет наименьший приоритет. В таком случае нам необходимо отдельно рассмотреть правую часть данной операции. Очевидно, что изначально необходимо выполнить унарные операции, а уже потом переходить к бинарной. Но какую операцию делать в первую очередь? Это достаточно принципиально, так как от этого зависит результат выполнения программы. Если верить таблице, то сначала я должен вычислить инкремент/декремент, а потом уже переходить к их перемножению. Поскольку постфиксная форма имеет более высокий приоритет, то сначала я провожу операцию `y--`, а уже потом `++y`. В общем, если всё делать так, как я это понимаю, то в результате должно получиться `100`. Пишу данный код в своей IDE и вывожу его на консоль. Результат: `121`. Почему так? Неправильно расписана таблица приоритетов? Или же я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Друзья, спасибо всем за помощь! Мозговой штурм действительно работает, убедился в этом на своей собственной шкуре. Знаю, что данная тема вводит в ступор многих начинающих программистов, поэтому решил расписать свои соображения на данный счёт. Надеюсь, что судить строго не будете.

Итак, давайте начнём разбираться в этом вопросе. В чём основная проблема людей (в том числе и моя) в понимании данной темы? А проблема в том, что мы путаем *«приоритет»* с обычным порядком выполнения операторов. В каком порядке *JVM* выполняет инструкции? Очевидно, что все инструкции (а также операторы составных выражений) выполняются в привычном нам левоассоциативном направлении (слева направо), а когда мы доходим до конца строки (как правило в конце каждой строки ставится специальный *Unicode*-символ (или их комбинация), который является ограничителем строк (в основном это символы, которые имеют мнемоническое обозначение **CR+LF**)), то мы переходим на нижестоящую строчку и выполняем код с самого начала в том же левостороннем направлении (можно представить это как возврат каретки в самое начало строки в пишущей машинке, а затем перевод той же каретки в начало следующей строки).

Когда же начинаются основные сложности? Все неурядицы возникают ровным счётом тогда, когда мы сталкиваемся с некоторой *неопределённостью*. Что я имею в виду? Давайте рассмотрим классический пример применения на практике таблицы приоритетов операторов. Возьмём следующее арифметическое выражение:

```
/*
* Some code
*/ 

int z = a + b * c;
```

Ещё с начальной школы мы знаем, что сперва выполняются мультипликативные операции, а затем уже аддитивные, так как первые имеют явный приоритет над вторыми. Как это реализовано в самой *Java'е* и какая здесь может возникнуть коллизия? Мы видим в правой части операции присваивания составное выражение, которое состоит из двух бинарных арифметических операторов и 3-х операндов. Очевидно, что у нас есть два возможных пути, которые будут пересекаться в одном месте. Мы можем сделать так:

```
(a + b) * с;
```

Или же так:

```
a + (b * c);
```

Коллизия заключается в том, что в обеих случаях мы захватываем переменную *b*, которая одновременно является одним из операндов относительно обеих операторов. Понятное дело, что конечный результат будет разниться в зависимости от выбранного пути. Вот тут и вступают в дело приоритеты операторов! Мы прекрасно знаем, что операция умножения будет выполняться первой, ведь для нас это весьма очевидно и мы даже не обращаем на это внимания (хотя всё это изначально прописано в "мозгах" самой *JVM*).

А теперь хотелось бы перейти к более сложному примеру, с которого всё и начиналось. Почему же инкремент/декремент записанный в постфиксной нотации имеет приоритет над префиксной формой той же записи? Настолько я понял, то в обеих случаях можно привести лишь по одному примеру, где может возникнуть явная неопределённость. Приведём эти примеры:

```
a---b;
a+++b;
```

Такая форма записи допускает всего 2 возможных варианта без ошибки времени компиляции. Здесь можно выделить 2 оператора, один из которых будет бинарным оператором (сложения или вычитания), а также унарный инкремент/декремент (о форме записи пока ничего не говорим). Здесь уже возникает немного другого рода неопределённость, которая отличается от первого рассмотренного нами случая. Если в первом случае возникла коллизия на уровне совместно используемого операнда, то здесь возникает двусмысленность в вопросе унарного оператора, который может быть постфиксным/префиксным инкрементом/декрементом, как для переменной *a*, так и для переменной *b*. Имеем следующие варианты раскрытия скобок:

```
(a--)-b;     
a-(--b);

(a++)+b;
a+(++b);
```

Положение бинарного оператора имеет принципиальное значение только в первом случае, так как вычитание является антикоммутативной операций, а сложение, напротив, коммутативной. Хотелось бы добавить, что такой приоритет появился совсем не случайно. Чтобы понять это, необходимо обратиться к [*JLS*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

> The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the
>   result does not ultimately make a correct program while another
>   lexical translation would. There is one exception: if lexical
>   translation occurs in a type context (§4.11) and the input stream has
>   two or more consecutive > characters that are followed by a non->
>   character, then each > character must be translated to the token for
>   the numerical comparison operator >.
>
> *The input characters a--b are tokenized (§3.5) as a, --, b, which is*
>   *not part of any grammatically correct program, even though the*
>   *tokenization a, -, -, b could be part of a grammatically correct*
>   *program.*
>
> *Without the rule for > characters, two consecutive > brackets in a*
>   *type such as List> would be tokenized as the signed right*
>   *shift operator >>, while three consecutive > brackets in a type such*
>   *as List>> would be tokenized as the unsigned right*
>   *shift operator >>>. Worse, the tokenization of four or more*
>   *consecutive > brackets in a type such as*
>   *List>>> would be ambiguous, as various*
>   *combinations of >, >>, and >>> tokens could represent the >>>>*
>   *characters.*

Как мы можем понять, на каждом этапе используется наиболее длинная трансляция, даже если она приводит к некорректной программе. Скорее всего именно по этой причине постфиксная форма унарных операторов имеет некоторый приоритет над префиксной, это вписывается в общую логику лексической транляции, тем более других примеров в которых могла бы возникнуть коллизия между такого рода операторами придумать не то чтобы трудно, а скорее всего невозможно (во всяком случае, лично я не вижу других возможных вариантов написания корректной программы, где можно было бы смоделировать данную ситуацию).

Напоследок можно рассмотреть пример с логическими операторами.

```
boolean bool = a ^ b & c | d;

где a, b, c, d — переменные логического типа.
```

Чтобы понять, какая операция будет выполняться первой, было бы неплохо заглянуть вот [сюда](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). Зная приоритет каждого из операторов находим правильное решение:

```
boolean bool = ((a ^ (b & c)) | d);
```

Что хотелось бы сказать напоследок? В глобальной сети можно найти очень много ложных таблиц, которые могут ввести в заблуждение. Авторы добавляют туда всякую "отсебятину", по типу разделителей, оператора *new*, операторы приведения типов и прочую чепуху. Считаю, что есть единственный источник к которому можно обратиться в данном вопросе, это официальный сайт корпорации **Oracle**. И да, соглашусь с тем, что лучше использовать обычные скобки для коррекции приоритетов! :) Благодарю всех за внимание! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Операция `++y` выполняется непосредственно перед тем как значение `y` будет подставлено в выражение.
Операция `y--` сразу после.

Пример 1:

```
y= 10
z = ++y * y--
----------------------------
y = y + 1
z = 11 * 11 // 11*11 = 121
y = y - 1
```

Пример 2:

```
z = (y++) * (++y)
----------------------------   
z = 10 * (++y)
y = y + 1
y = y + 1
z = 10 * 12 // 10*12 = 120
```

**UPD:** JLS утверждает что существуют [первичные выражения](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8)

> Первичные выражения включают в себя большинство простейших видов
>   выражений, из которых строятся другие: литералы, создание объектов,
>   обращения к полям, вызовы методов, ссылки на методы и обращения к
>   массиву. Выражение в скобках также рассматривается синтаксически как
>   первичное выражение.

[постфиксные выражения](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14)

> Постфиксные выражения включают использование операторов postfix ++ и
>   -. Они не считаются первичными выражениями (§15.8), но обрабатываются отдельно в грамматике, чтобы избежать определенных
>   неоднозначностей. И становятся взаимозаменяемыми только здесь, на
>   уровне приоритета постфиксных выражений.

и [унарные операторы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15)

> Оператор +, -, ++, --, ~, !, и оператор приведения типа (§15.16)
>   называются унарными операторами.

Видно что постфиксные операции занимают отдельную позицию в структуре выражений Java, где-то между вызовами методов и унарными операторами. Соответственно им должен быть назначен определенный уровень приоритета. JLS не объясняет конкретно, почему это было сделано, оправдываясь "определенными неоднозначностями". Можно предположить, что это относиться к удобству парсинга выражений или определенной реализации его механизма.

Как выяснили в соседних ответах, столкнуться с конфликтом префиксных и постфиксных операторов или неоднозначностью выражения с их использованием достаточно сложно, и  на практику написания кода такое разделение уровней приоритетов сильно не влияет.

Comment: Этот механизм мне вполне ясен. Здесь Вы мне описали различие между постфиксной и префиксной нотациями операций инкремента и декремента. Меня интересует немного другое. Есть таблица в которой расписан приоритет всех существующих в языке программирования Java операций. Этот приоритет используется для разрешения разногласий (помогает определить правильный порядок выполнения операций) в сложных составных арифметических и логических выражениях. Так вот, почему постфикская форма имеет по таблицам приоритет над префиксной, хотя на практике мы этого почему-то не видим?

Comment: Постарался сформулировать все что накопал в UPD. Похоже что это рудимент или следствие каких то особенностей Java, что постфиксные операции вынесены на отдельный уровень,  а не специально установленное правило.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы разобраться, достаточно открыть `.class` файл и посмотреть как `java` его декомпилировала:

```
    int y = 10;
    int y = y + 1; // 11
    int z = y * y--; // 11 * 11, потом y = y - 1, но это уже не важно, т.к. `y` больше не используется
    System.out.println("z = " + z);
```

Comment: Хорошо, но если следовать таблице приоритетов, то разве операция `y--` в составном выражении `z = y * y--` не должна выполняться первой?

Comment: нет. Вот, чтобы лучше понять, как java поймет выражение `i+++i`? Как `i + ++i` или `i++ + i`? А выражения - слева направо считаются

Answer (score 1):

Значение подставляется сразу после выполнения операции. То есть, выполнив ++y оно вернет значение 11 на место операции, а в месте y-- сначала вернет 11, а потом уменьшит y на единицу. И выходит что 11*11

Я как-то даже не обращал внимание, что у постфиксных унарных операторов приоритет выше. Выполняются они все в порядке очереди. Интересно

Почему оно так работает, вроде бы понятно.  Приоритет нужен в случае решения конфликта, когда два оператора разных приоритетов сталкиваются на одном уровне. То есть (a + b*b) сразу ясно что выполнять первым необходимо умножение, а в случае (a+a == b*b) смысла выполнять первым именно операцию умножение нет, идя в порядке слева направо получим тот же результат.

Приоритет операторов ++/-- помог бы решить ситуацию вроде (++a--), указывающий, что сначала нужно выполнить именно уменьшение переменной, но такая конструкция запрещена, да и смыла в ней мало. В случае с (++a * a--) выполнятся будет слева направо. А из=за того, что унарные операции изменяют саму переменную, мы можем проследить какая операция в действительности выполняется первая, хотя по сути это не должно иметь значения. Их нужно использовать с осторожностью

Comment: Это понятно, так получается, если двигаться в естественном направлении. Но почему же тогда даже в официальном учебнике Java от Oracle пишут такие вещи? В чём загвоздка? Если интересно, то посмотрите сами, может быть просто я что-то не так понял. Вот (из раздела The Java™ Tutorials): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Просил бы Вас обратить особенное внимание на саму таблицу приоритетов (Operator Precedence).

Comment: @Lexoid Я не понял, что вас смущает. Описание приоритетов на сайте Oracle и в других местах вполне согласуется с теми ответами, которые вам дали, и с тем результатом, который у вас получается.

Comment: @m. vokhm Я не могу сказать, что меня что-то не устраивает. Прекрасно понимаю, каким именно образом и в каком порядке выполняются унарные операции инкремента и декремента. Просто это немного не состыковывается с тем, что приведено в качестве официального пособия на веб-сайте Oracle в разделе The Java™ Tutorials. Давайте попробуем разобраться с этим. Что же такое «приоритет выполнения операторов» и зачем он вообще необходим? Какой в этом практический смысл? Лично в моём понимании всё обстоит примерно следующим образом.

Comment: Приоритет необходим исключительно для того, чтобы определить порядок выполнения операторов, которые сами являются частью более сложного составного арифметического или логического выражения. Это очевидные вещи о которых даже говорить как-то стыдно.

Comment: Но вот какой непонятный для меня казус возникает... Если в The Java™ Tutorials явно указано, что операции постфиксного инкремента/декремента имеют безусловный приоритет над теми же унарными операциями, которые, правда, записаны в префиксной нотации, то почему же тогда всё выполняется в обычном левоассоциативном порядке, будто бы эти операторы имеют одинаковый приоритет (на практике так и получается, если честно)?

Comment: Или же я не понимаю сам функционал всей этой системы приоритетов, или же что-то ещё... Могу ли я получить ответ на этот вопрос? P.S. Мне просто кажется, что некоторые пользователи меня не совсем правильно поняли, так как начали мне расписывать разницу между префиксной и постфиксной формами инкремента/декремента, хотя сам вопрос был немного не об этом.

Comment: @Lexoid более высокий приоритет определяет ЧТО будет обработано на данном этапе, а не в какой последовательности. Выражение (a---a) может быть истолковано двумя способами (a - (--a)) и ((a--) -a). Поскольку приоритет у постфиксного оператора выше, то будет выполнен именно второй вариант. Сложно придумать пример, из которого действительно была бы видна разница, но для компилятора она точно есть. Проверить что это именно так, можно просмотрев скомпилированный класс